# MySQL Not Showing Data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic script below to show values from a database; it has worked for years now, but suddenly I'm getting empty results with no errors.

I'm thinking maybe the way to query data has changed? My script is below (note the db login details are correct, and connection is fine):

```
    <?php
    // Get Database Login
    define("DB", dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/");
    require(DB . "../../ipSecure/db.ipSecure.php");
    // End

    // Connect To Database
    $conn = mysql_connect($ipSecure_dbhost, $ipSecure_dbuser, $ipSecure_dbpass) or die ("Error Connecting to MYSQL");
    mysql_select_db($ipSecure_dbname);
    // End

    // Find ipSecure Status
    $ipSlicense = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `license` WHERE `c_id` = 'inkgear-josh'");
    $ipSlicense_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($ipSlicense);

    // Show ipSecure Status
    echo $ipSlicense_result["c_id"];
    // End
    ?>
```

Comment: @Stilly.stack You can't echo an array.

Comment: What does `var_dump($ipSlicense_result)` show?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Chances are, you'll get a deprecated error message. 9 times out of 10 these past few weeks, that's what it's been. If it doesn't show you that message, then it could help in another way. Plus, have you defined `$ipSecure_dbname` in your include file by any chance? I don't see it defined anywhere in your code and there's no indication of it.

Comment: u have turn on errors and its showing no errors

Comment: var_dump($ipSlicense_result); is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php
// Get Database Login
define("DB", dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/");
require(DB . "../../ipSecure/db.ipSecure.php");
// End

// Connect To Database
/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */
$conn=mysqli_connect($ipSecure_dbhost,$ipSecure_dbuser,$ipSecure_dbpass,$ipSecure_dbname);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}
// End


// Find ipSecure Status
$ipSlicense = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `license`");
while ($ipSlicense_result = mysqli_fetch_array($ipSlicense)){

// Show ipSecure Status
echo $ipSlicense_result['c_id'];
echo " - ".$ipSlicense_result['company_name']."; Status: ".$ipSlicense_result['status']."<br>";

// End

}

?>
```

I've convert your code to **MySQLi** at least, instead of deprecated **MySQL**.

Comment: If it's not showing anything when echoing the first row alone, how would calling it in a loop fix it?

Comment: Can you also include your license table structure? So I can analyze it better. And is there a inkgear-josh value inside c_id column?

Comment: @Barmar - updated my answer. Please take a look. Forgot to include $conn in your query.

Comment: If `c_id` is unique, as ID fields usually are, the query can only return 1 row, so there's no point in using a `while` loop. The application has been running without the loop for years, they probably don't want multiple results.

Comment: yea i have used above mysqli code and still returns blank result with no errors, license table has 3 rows c_id, company name and status

Comment: if i use above code and echo $ipSlicense; i get error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /home/ipsecure/public_html/license/inkgear-josh/index.php on line 23

Comment: You get the error because you try to echo $ipSlicense, which is a query and not a string, instead of the $ipSlicense_result['c_id']

Comment: And are you sure about your query? That c_id has inkgear-josh value? And what is the type of your c_id column?

Comment: Try again my updated answer. I've removed temporarily the WHERE on your query. Because I have a little doubt about it.

Comment: ok i have just played with it this is really weird if i call company_name using the company name which is another db table it shows my result but it cant search via c_id anymore?

Comment: found the problem need to update my sql tables they must have been old: Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

Comment: You also have another table named company name? Or are you confusing yourself from table to column? And a little advice, try not to name your column, tables, etc with spaces. And Yes, you can still search via c_id with a proper query.

Comment: yea ok i have fixed the problem the table c_id was a varchar and using inkgear-josh it would not recognise the - so ive changed to just inkgear and now it works

Comment: Good for you, @user3618689. But if you still found my answer helpful in any other way, you can still accept my answer or even at least up-vote it.